# How to resolve the failing of creating Sentinel Alert Rule Scheduled using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, azure-sentinel

I am trying to deploy a Microsoft Sentinel solution with a `Sentinel Alert Automation Rule` and a `Sentinel Alert Rule Scheduled`. I use a service principal to assign `Microsoft Sentinel Automation Contributor` so that it can create the Automation rules which has playbooks to run (such automation rules are not included in the code yet). However when I run `terraform apply`, it fails to create the Alert Rule Scheduled giving me an error about a workbook not found. I have not created a workbook with the id they are giving. Can somebody explain why is that happening and how to resolve it please?

#### Code:

```
terraform {}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg-sentinel-alert-rule-test"
  location = "eastus2"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "example-workspace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding" "example" {
  workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id

  depends_on = [azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example]
}

data "azuread_service_principal" "security_insight" {
  display_name = "Azure Security Insights"

  depends_on = [azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sentinel_automation_contributor" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Microsoft Sentinel Automation Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.security_insight.object_id

  depends_on = [azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example]
}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "example" {
  name                       = "example"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example.workspace_id
  display_name               = "example"
  severity                   = "High"
  query                      = <<QUERY
AzureActivity |
  where OperationName == "Create or Update Virtual Machine" or OperationName =="Create Deployment" |
  where ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" |
  make-series dcount(ResourceId) default=0 on EventSubmissionTimestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 1d) by Caller
QUERY

  depends_on = [azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example]
}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_automation_rule" "example" {
  name                       = "56094f72-ac3f-40e7-a0c0-47bd95f70336"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example.workspace_id
  display_name               = "automation_rule1"
  order                      = 1
  action_incident {
    order  = 1
    status = "Active"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_role_assignment.sentinel_automation_contributor]
}
```

#### Error:

```
Error: creating Sentinel Alert Rule Scheduled "Alert Rule (Subscription: \"{my-subscription-id}\"\n
Resource Group Name: \"rg-sentinel-alert-rule-test\"\n
Workspace Name: \"example-workspace\"\nRule: \"example\")":
alertrules.AlertRulesClient#AlertRulesCreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request:
StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400
Code="BadRequest" Message="Failed to run the analytics rule query. Log Analytics
workspace 'b819562b-650e-4277-9035-c89a1f6d64c5' could not be found."
│ 
│   with azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled.example,
│   on main.tf line 41, in resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "example":
│   41: resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "example" {
│ 
╵
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using terraform provider version 3.40 and

I have checked with  `log_analytics_workspace_id =  azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example.workspace_id`    which gave errors.
I am using terraform version 3.40:

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "example" {
name = "examplekaalertrule"
log_analytics_workspace_id =  azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example.workspace_id  
display_name = "examplesentielrule"
severity = "High"
query = <<QUERY
AzureActivity |
where OperationName == "Create or Update Virtual Machine" or OperationName =="Create Deployment" |
where ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" |
make-series dcount(ResourceId) default=0 on EventSubmissionTimestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 1d) by Caller
QUERY

depends_on = [
  azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example
]
}
```

[image: ]]

Check the following code that worked for me.

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "rgcore-management-la" {
  name                = "la-example-utv-weu"
 location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 90
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "example" {
  solution_name         = "SecurityInsights"
 location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.rgcore-management-la.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.rgcore-management-la.name
  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/SecurityInsights"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.rgcore-management-la]

}



resource "azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding" "example" {
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  workspace_name               = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.rgcore-management-la.name
  customer_managed_key_enabled = false

}




resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "example" {
name = "examplekaalertrule"
log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_solution.example.workspace_resource_id 
display_name = "examplesentielrule"
severity = "High"
query = <<QUERY
AzureActivity |
where OperationName == "Create or Update Virtual Machine" or OperationName =="Create Deployment" |
where ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" |
make-series dcount(ResourceId) default=0 on EventSubmissionTimestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 1d) by Caller
QUERY

depends_on = [
  azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example
]
}
```

[image]

[image]

With terraform provider version 3.5.0 and az cli version 2.30, even following code which is code provide by you worked.

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "management-la" {
  name                = "example-weu"
 location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 90
}



resource "azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding" "example" {
  workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.management-la.id
}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "example" {
  name                       = "edfgxample"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.example.workspace_id
  display_name               = "exghjample"
  severity                   = "High"
  query                      = <<QUERY
AzureActivity |
  where OperationName == "Create or Update Virtual Machine" or OperationName =="Create Deployment" |
  where ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" |
  make-series dcount(ResourceId) default=0 on EventSubmissionTimestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 1d) by Caller
QUERY
}
```

[image]

***Check if you have the necessary permissions to access the Log Analytics workspace. The Azure AD user or service principal this is used to run the code has 'Contributor' role on the Log Analytics workspace.***

***Also make sure if  Log Analytics workspace is deleted or destroyed.***